# Deleted admin HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ and now there is no admin on the system

Tags: user-accounts, administrator, windows-registry

One of my colleagues has deleted the registry stuff related to the Administrator account on his PC and now he cannot see the "Administrator" account on the Windows machine!! There is just a "Guest" account which can be logged in[there is no switch user option]

So we tried to use "Run as administrator" option after logging in to the "Guest" account, the system does not recognize it either. It throws error or the button to click 'Yes' [to run as Administrator] is not getting enabled! Unfortunately there is no backup of the registry keys that were deleted. Can anything be done about this?!

Any suggestions about dealing with this will be extremely helpful as all his important files etc. are available on the other account. Thanks in advance.

edit: this is a Windows 7 machine

Comment: The answer is to restore from last known good configuration.

Comment: Pull the drive out and mount it on another system and backup all his files to a spare drive.  Reinstall, restore from the backup.

Comment: Do you have an IT department? I am guessing no... But if you do, bring it to them for their restore process and don't let him futz with the registry again. In fact, he obviously should not have admin on his machine!

Answer (score 0):

You could build a hiren's boot CD and use the offline password changer.. It is possible that it will allow you to create a new account.